# Is this serialVersionUID a universal version identifier?

Tags: java, eclipse, serialization, java-io

If I use Eclipse IDE generated default serialVersionUID as below

```
static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

How can it be universal version?
If so, why? How can it be universal version?
Anyone explanation please!

Comment: What is a universal version identifier?

Comment: 1. This field is important to serialisation implementations (suppose not all implementations) 2. What sense of word "version" (universal version) do You use

Comment: This field is used when serializing/deserializing the objects for each serialized class. So the value of this field needs to be unique, I think most people use this field as 'Universal version'. Am I right?

Comment: @StephenTunAung It doesn't need to be unique, it just needs to be 'unique' between (serialization) incompatible versions of the same class.

Comment: Thank you very much @MarkRotteveel I should go through it.

Answer (score 1):

The [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) explains it well:

> The serialization runtime associates with each serializable class a
>   version number, called a serialVersionUID, which is used during
>   deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized
>   object have loaded classes for that object that are compatible with
>   respect to serialization. If the receiver has loaded a class for the
>   object that has a different serialVersionUID than that of the
>   corresponding sender's class, then deserialization will result in an
>   InvalidClassException. A serializable class can declare its own
>   serialVersionUID explicitly by declaring a field named
>   "serialVersionUID" that must be static, final, and of type long:
>
> ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
>
> If a serializable class does not explicitly declare a
>   serialVersionUID, then the serialization runtime will calculate a
>   default serialVersionUID value for that class based on various aspects
>   of the class, as described in the Java(TM) Object Serialization
>   Specification. However, it is strongly recommended that all
>   serializable classes explicitly declare serialVersionUID values, since
>   the default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class
>   details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can
>   thus result in unexpected InvalidClassExceptions during
>   deserialization. Therefore, to guarantee a consistent serialVersionUID
>   value across different java compiler implementations, a serializable
>   class must declare an explicit serialVersionUID value. It is also
>   strongly advised that explicit serialVersionUID declarations use the
>   private modifier where possible, since such declarations apply only to
>   the immediately declaring class--serialVersionUID fields are not
>   useful as inherited members.

Also a good read: [Always Declare Serial Version Uid](http://c2.com/ppr/wiki/JavaIdioms/AlwaysDeclareSerialVersionUid.html)